# biplot of PCA data gives very unusual

Tags: r, pca, biplot, astronomy

Very much a new at data analytics, with some functional understanding of statistics.  I was referred to this site from elsewhere.
I am looking at ca. 1000 optical spectra, data available from the Sloan Digital Sky Survey, for [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWnI3.png) data reduction], and [2] to understand if there are any spectral features that might stand out when compared to the average spectra.
I tested my code on model data, and I was able to reproduce results found on various sites.  When I ran my code on my spectral data set, and constructed a biplot, I got a very unusual shape, alomost like a semi-symmetrical ellipse.  I have no idea what it is I am looking at, would be very grateful if someone could share their expertise.
Thanks.[image]

Comment: Very cool! Are you saying you would like clarification as to what a bi plot is, or in interpreting this plot specifically?

Comment: Hi Tanner, pardon my lack of clarity.  I have looked at numerous biplot images via google, but saw nothing like this.  If you could shed some light on why the plot is so strangely shaped it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm.. my guess would be that essentially PCA1 is a measure of distance. The strange distribution of the variables is due to the red-shift phenomena-- so different colors that are closer to red are pointing in one direction, and then slowly they transition towards the other direction. My guess is PC1 is a measure of distance from the earth.

Comment: As for the curve, I'm not sure, but it's cool! This may have to do with the fact that the data you have is fundamentally tied to 3-diemensional co-ordinates, and so you are effectively attempting to reduce spherical data down to linear data. Essentially, you are trying to map the sky onto a square picture, so you have the same weird curvature you get on some map projections.